# How to run an algorithm only for a time in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, algorithm

So, Let's say I want to do endless calculations and in a given moment I want to stop the algorithm and get the result at that time. How can I do that in python?

For example, imagine that function running for 10 secs, is there a way that I can get the value of x?

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__x = x

  def inititySum(self):
    while(True):
      self.__x += 1

A = MyClass(0)
A.infinitySum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multiprocessing` and initialize a `Process` to run the function then you can get the value of `x` whenever you want, and make sure you `terminate()` the process or you will reach integer overflow. However, when using `multiprocessing` different processes don't share variables so you have to initialize your `x` as a shared variable between processes. For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = multiprocessing.Value('i', x)

    def infinitySum(self):
        while True:
            self.x.value += 1

A = MyClass(0)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=A.infinitySum)
p.start()
time.sleep(5)
p.terminate()
print(A.x.value) # output: 3834689
```